# Why does not the preview of the loaded image appear?

Tags: 8, javascript

When I load an image into a Drupal 8 form, JS errors appear in the console and the file link is not displayed. I have a limit of 10 MB per file in Drupal. If I load an image of 1 MB or less, it works. If I load an image of more than 1MB, it does not load and there are errors in the consoles :

[image]

I load an image of less than 1 MB, it works:

[image]

I load an image of more than 1 MB, it is a failure (errors in the console and no warning) :

[image]

The form fields and my server are correctly configured :

[image]

The server and Drupal seem to me correctly set. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have access to the nginx configuration for this website? If so, you can add the following to the configuration and see what happens. It might set already to 1m:

```
http {
    #...
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    #...
}
```

Comment: perfect thank you